# Why Doesn't Inheritance Work With Values?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I need to create in my application multiple instance of a same class.
In this class, I need to access properties from other classes, and I don't really want to push my properties in all my classes at their construction.

So I thought I could make this class inheriting from a parent which has all the properties I need.

For instance:

```
// This class is called only once at the start of my app
class Parent
{
    int Property1 = 0;

    public Parent(int val)
    {
        this.Property1 = val;
    }
}


class Child : Parent
{
    public Child()
    {
    }

    public void PrintProp()
    {
        // Will always print the value of Parent's Property1 which has been defined only once
        Console.WriteLine(Property1);
    }
}
```

Problem with that code is that each time I define a new Child(), Property1 value is 0, and not the value I sent it at my program startup.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This sounds like `Parent` is supposed to hold some kind of configuration. If that’s the case, just pass the instance of that type around at every child construction. Inheritance won’t help you here.

Comment: is property1 global for all instances, or different for each object instantiated?

Comment: How does the `child` know that its parent is `parent`?

Comment: Actually the code wont compile! the compiler will complain about `Parent does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments', removing the error will solve the problem.

Comment: @ApocKalipsS can you clarify what you mean by " I don't really want to push my properties in all my classes at their construction."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inheritance in object-oriented programming languages is a mechanism for association of classes that maintain an *is* relationship.[1](http://se.ethz.ch/~meyer/publications/computer/taxonomy.pdf)

See [this article](http://se.ethz.ch/~meyer/publications/computer/taxonomy.pdf) for a perspective from the author of the [Eiffel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiffel_%28programming_language%29) programming language.

See also [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29) for more details.  (I would be remiss in noting that at the present time the document is poorly sourced.)

It appears that what you are trying to accomplish is something akin to a global value or sharing of values across instances.  See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753197%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for a mechanism that is doing that in the Windows Presentation Framework.

If you want a new instance to have the same values as another instance, you will need to copy those values over or make one instance point to another instance object for its values.

For sharing global values in an object-oriented way, please take a look at the [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Comment: Actually using inheritance just for code reuse is a bad practice that will be end up in Yo-yo anti-pattern in large scale projects! The main reasons to use inheritance will be Dynamic binding and Polymorphism .